# Free models of infinitary essentially algebraic theories

Tags: logic, category-theory, model-theory

Let $\mathbb{T}$ be an essentially algebraic theory in which the operations are allowed to have infinite arity. It is known that not every such theory has a free/initial model; for example, there is no free complete Boolean algebra on countably many generators. However, there are infinitary essentially algebraic theories that *do* have initial models, for example the theory of sheaves on a small site.

My question is: is it known whether there are any conditions on an infinitary essentially algebraic theory $\mathbb{T}$ that will guarantee that it has a free/initial model? For example, will $\mathbb{T}$ have an initial model if the arities of all the operations are bounded by some cardinal?

Comment: If there is a regular cardinal $\lambda$ such that every operation has arity less than $\lambda$, then initial models exist. This is because the essentially algebraic theory is then a $\lambda$-ary essentially algebraic theory, which do have initial models. The problem arises specifically when the arities are unbounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @varkor pointed out, if $\mathbb{T}$ is a $\lambda$-ary essentially algebraic theory for some regular cardinal $\lambda$, then $\mathbb{T}$ does have an initial model. This follows (e.g.) by (the proof of) Theorem 3.36 in the book *Locally Presentable and Accessible Categories* by Adamek and Rosicky, in which it is shown that if $\mathbb{T}$ is a $\lambda$-ary essentially algebraic theory over a $\lambda$-ary signature $\Sigma$, then its category of (set-based) models is a reflective subcategory of the category of partial $\Sigma$-structures. An easy computation then shows that the reflection of the initial/empty partial $\Sigma$-structure is the initial model of $\mathbb{T}$.